# How to configure facebook signup/signin for Spring Boot using signup/signin adapters?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

I'd like to implement Social signup/signin functionality besides my existing signup/signin functionality using jwt.

I followed this tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/facebook-authentication-with-spring-security-and-social , but the the Autowiring of the Social Security related classes : ConnectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository, doesn't seem to work, even though the example suggests it should.

How and where do I define these beans? I can't seem to find any good examples on this.

I want to end up with the signup/signin adapters that call my existing functionality in UserService.

https://www.baeldung.com/facebook-authentication-with-spring-security-and-social

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.lolsocial.baeldung.security" 
})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator;

@Autowired
private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

@Autowired
private FacebookConnectionSignup facebookConnectionSignup;

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout();
} // @formatter:on

@Bean
// @Primary
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
    ((InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository) 
usersConnectionRepository).setConnectionSignUp(facebookConnectionSignup);
    return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, 
usersConnectionRepository, new FacebookSignInAdapter());
}
}
```

Expected : Have signin/signup adapters working that just call the signin()/signup() methods in my UserService.

Actual: Currently not working due to the Social Security beans not getting autowired.( ConnectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository )

Autowiring failing

[image: autowiring failing]

Answer (score 0):

The configurations you are using should work well with Spring Boot 1.x.

However, if you are using Boot 2.x, then you need to define the `ConnectionFactoryLocator` and `UsersConnectionRepository` in your SecurityConfig:

```
private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(appId, appSecret));
    return registry;
}

private UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
    return new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
}
```

Here, `appId` and `appSecret` are coming from application.properties.

You also need to change the implementation for your `ProviderSignInController` bean:

```
@Bean
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
    ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator = connectionFactoryLocator();
    UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository = getUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
    ((InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository) usersConnectionRepository).setConnectionSignUp(facebookConnectionSignup);
    return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new FacebookSignInAdapter());
}
```

For further details, please refer to the Baeldung article you mentioned, it has since been updated.